# Case from Chatter question isnt working in lightning

Tags: lightning, community, chatter, feeditem

I have strange issue happening on my instance
I have case created from chatter question in the community (by process builder + quick action) 
yet when trying to reply from the chatter in the case I get error
"The post was deleted." 
yet in classic it works fine...
did anyone encountered it? 
is there a better / correct way to create case from chatter question? 
[image]